# ScalaFX i18n with fxml not working

Tags: scala, internationalization, fxml, scalafx, fxmlloader

First the working code:

```
val root: BorderPane = new BorderPane(jfxf.FXMLLoader.load(getClass.getResource("/GUI/main.fxml")))

stage = new PrimaryStage()
{
  title = "FXML Test"
  scene = new Scene(root)
}
```

No problem here. Now I wanted to add i18n support like so:

```
val bundle: ResourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(getClass.getResource("/i18n/en.properties").openStream)
val loader: FXMLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass.getResource("/GUI/main.fxml"), bundle)
val root = loader.load[jfxs.Parent]

stage = new PrimaryStage()
{
  title = "FXML Test"
  scene = new Scene(root)
}
```

Now the constructor `scene = new Scene(root)` cannot be resolved.

I tried to solve this by

1) initializing a new BorderPane, like:

```
val root = new BorderPane(loader.load[jfxs.Parent])
```

But the constructor of BorderPane cannot be resolved so I tried

2) casting it to a BorderPane, like:

```
val root = new BorderPane(loader.load[jfxs.Parent].asInstanceOf[BorderPane])
```

which is okay in the IDE but throws a compiler-error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane cannot be cast to
>   scalafx.scene.layout.BorderPane

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Now the constructor `scene = new Scene(root)` cannot be resolved.": that would be because the `scalafx.scene.Scene` constructor expects a parameter of type `scalafx.scene.Parent` and not `javafx.scene.Parent`.

Just add `import scalafx.Includes._` to your imports to use ScalaFX's implicit conversions. You can then do:

```
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.{scene => jfxs}

import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene

object MyApp extends JFXApp{
  val bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(getClass.getResource("/i18n/en.properties").openStream)
  val fxml = getClass.getResource("/GUI/main.fxml")
  val root: jfxs.Parent = FXMLLoader.load(fxml, bundle)

  stage = new PrimaryStage() {
    title = "FXML Test"
    scene = new Scene(root) // root is implicitly converted to scalafx.scene.Parent
  }
}
```